# Is there a way to check/validate that every nodes have a edge connected in react-flow-renderer?

Tags: reactjs

i am using the save and restore example and i want to validate/check ik every node have e connected edge before saving the object. for example how to check if node 2 to 3, 3 to 4 have a edge connected.

```
// nodes and edges
 [
  {
    id: '1',
    type: 'input',
    data: { label: 'Node 1' },
    position: { x: 250, y: 5 },
  },
  { id: '2', data: { label: 'Node 2' }, position: { x: 100, y: 100 } },
  { id: '3', data: { label: 'Node 3' }, position: { x: 400, y: 100 } },
  { id: '4', data: { label: 'Node 4' }, position: { x: 400, y: 200 } },
  {
    id: 'e1-2',
    source: '1',
    target: '2',
  },
  //{ id: 'e1-3', source: '1', target: '3' },
];
```